# How to exclude source files by configuration in CLion?

Tags: c++, c, ide, clion

As shown below, Threre are two directories that are exclusively included in the build depending on the build option. (by setting CMake)

```
ROOT
  -- src
    -- moduleA
      -- codeA.c
    -- moduleB
      -- codeB.c
    commonCode.c
```

`funcSameNameDifferentImpl` function exist in both codeA.c and codeB.c. It is used in `commonCode.c`

In this case, how I exclude `codeA.c` from CLion source control indexing? When I try to navigate or go to definition, IDE is NOT working as I expected. Even IDE bring me to source file excluded in build with kind warning 'This file does not belong to any project...'

I found out below guide and check overriding file type as plain text is working well. But, I think it is too ugly, not elegant.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/controlling-source-library-and-exclude-directories.html

Is there a nice way to exclude files and directories from CLion indexing?

I think it's intuitive behavior for indexing to change automatically depending on the build target.

Comment: You "exclude" the files by not having them be part of your project? You can't build with both "modules" anyway, you must have some way to select which "module" to build with. If you implement that in your main `CMakeLists.txt` file then the unused module should not be part of the project and won't be indexed.

Comment: If files are within a directory that is included by CMake, you can right click on the directory and select 'Mark as' --> 'excluded'. However it only works with directory.